# Facebook: iframe not resizing in firefox

Tags: jquery, facebook, firefox, iframe

I have an iframe that resizes perfectly to fit canvas content in both chrome and ie but when it comes to firefox, i get stuck with with horrible horizontal/vertical scrollbars which i do not want.

I have Auto resize turned on in the facebook app dev and have tried explicitly setting the size via

```
FB.Canvas.setSize
```

etc... but that was no good

Have tried using the autoGrow method which works for the default page (although it's far from perfect) but any tabbed pages don't seem to resize.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have tried this but this seams to work for me. I set the height in the app settings to fluid and then i add this code in

```
<!--Get jQuery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.Canvas.setSize();}
</script>
```

then after and for the body tag i add this

```
<body style='overflow: hidden' >
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script> 

<script>
FB.init({  
appId  : "APP_ID", 
status : true, //check login status  
cookie : true, //enable cookies to allow the server to access the session  
xfbml  : true  //parse XFBML 
 });  
 FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);
</script>
```

Try using that :)

Comment: Yep, canvas width and height were fixed, changing them to fluid fixed it. Using `setAutoGrow();` instead of `setAutoResize();` as it's deprecated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that sometimes these methods can be a little buggy, but if you keep calling them, the Facebook parent window eventually gets the message. This being the case, you may want to try something like this:

```
setInterval(FB.Canvas.setSize, 500);
```